Facing problem for printing Palindrome numbers from specific starting point to ending point

Write a C program to print a Palindrome number from 1 to 100.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
int temp, remainder, i, total = 0, startingNumber, endingNumber;

printf("Enter the starting point for checking palindrome number : \n");
scanf("%d", &startingNumber);

printf("Enter the ending point for checking palindrome number : \n");
scanf("%d", endingNumber);

for (i = startingNumber; i <= endingNumber; i++)

{


int reverseOfNumber = 0;

i = abs(i);

temp = i;

while (temp != 0)

    {


remainder = temp % 10;
reverseOfNumber = (reverseOfNumber * 10) + remainder;
temp /= 10;

    }



if (i == reverseOfNumber)

    {


printf("%d\n", i);
total++;

    }



}



printf("\nTHE TOTAL PALINDROME NUMBERS FROM(%d to %d) = %d\n", startingNumber, endingNumber,          total);

getchar();
}

I expect that, the output will be shown that- Palindrome numbers from start to end.`


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
